# Excel VBA - Dynamic Range

Tags: sql, excel, vba, loops

I have a list of numbers on a sheet that needs to be added to an array but in batches.  So I have list of 150 or so numbers on List, that needs to get added to an array but in batches of 5.  Each new batch will be used to query a SQL database.

The list can change length and will not be even, could be 20 could be 541.

Edit: This seems to do what I need but I am sure there is a better solution.

```
Dim i As Integer

Sheets("List").Select
lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

Range("a1").Select


For i = 1 To lRow

    begrng = ActiveCell.Address
    ActiveCell.Offset(4, 0).Select
    endrng = ActiveCell.Address


    Set rng = Range(begrng, endrng)


    For Each cell In rng
        If Not IsEmpty(cell) Then
        mystring = mystring & "','" & cell.Value
        End If
    Next cell

    mystring = Right(mystring, Len(mystring) - 2)
    mystring = ""

Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Show the code you have and we can work out how to tweak it

Comment: Why are you concatenating the values in the range? That suggests you would end up with 30 columns of 1 row each.

Comment: @SJR - I believe Mike is constructing a comma delimited list of quoted strings for an SQL SELECT using IN ('this', 'that', 'other').

Comment: @user10947436 , yes you are correct.  I didn't post all of my code, but I am basically trying to run a SQL statement in batches, return the results, then go back to the next group.  I cant run the entire list as it times out in SQL so I need to run these in batches.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try,

```
Dim i As Long, lRow As Long, mystring As String, ayes As Variant

With Worksheets("List")

    lRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    For i = 1 To lRow Step 5

        ayes = Application.Transpose(.Range(.Cells(i, "A"), .Cells(i + 4, "A")).Value2)

        mystring = Application.Trim(Join(ayes, Space(1)))
        ayes = Split(mystring, Space(1))
        mystring = Chr(39) & Join(ayes, "','") & Chr(39)

        Debug.Print mystring

    Next i
End With
```